# CsrfFilter always fires exception in Spring 6.0+

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf-token

In the new Spring Boot 3.0.1 I'm adding support for CSRF protection by adding this simple configuration as per Spring documentation:

```
http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository);
```

and

```
 @Bean
    public CsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository() {
        var tokenRepo = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        tokenRepo.setCookiePath("/");
        return tokenRepo;
    }
```

On the front-end side, there is an Angular app with import of the standard library

```
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

However I cannot make it work with the standard workflow, like

1. Execute request to get XCSRF-TOKEN cookie from the server.
2. Extract the token value from the cookie.
3. Add X-XSRF-TOKEN header with the extract value from the cookie.

The front-end sends both cookie and header with the same token value and it fails in check:

```
public final class XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler ...

private static String getTokenValue(String actualToken, String token) {
        byte[] actualBytes;
        try {
            actualBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(actualToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] tokenBytes = Utf8.encode(token);
        int tokenSize = tokenBytes.length;
        if (actualBytes.length < tokenSize) {
            return null;
        }
```

The methods always returns null for

```
if (actualBytes.length < tokenSize) {
            return null;
        }
```

The only way to make it work is to return encoded string to be pasted in the header directly by adding endpoint, like this:

```
 DeferredCsrfToken deferredCsrfToken = repository.loadDeferredToken(request, response);
        requestHandler.handle(request, response, deferredCsrfToken::get);
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");
        return csrfToken.getToken();
```

So the returned value to be used in header looks like:

```
ab5tfqabXomGPuLjDQk96mVMZHNOh_JnpPVM4F_hQU1sOMyWW9sLSsCtb72rWNPabyQJ01EpSUsvtctKwcQphWeAJX9ZDPmg
```

instead of

```
5adaf830-40e6-43c9-b42a-e36fd713c1a6
```

Any advice on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things changed with spring security 6.

The migration guide also mentioned changes to be aware of when using angular with HttpClientXsrfModule or similar on client side.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_angularjs_or_another_javascript_framework

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration/servlet/exploits.html

According to spring security migration guides following configurtation should work and is the recommended way.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
    CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
    // (optional) set null to opt out of deferred tokens
    requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);

    http
        // ...
        .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
            .csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository)
            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
        );

    return http.build();
}
```

For further details please read migration guides, so you can adapt to your needs.